# MS Access SQL Average function with decimals

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am trying to create a rating system for an item and have the average of all of the ratings show for that item on a form. I want the rating to have 1 decimal place. I came up with the code below:

```
SELECT OvrRate.OvRating, *
FROM tbl1 LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT Field1, ROUND(AVG(Rating),1) AS OvRating 
     FROM tbl_Review GROUP BY Field1)  AS OvrRate 
ON tbl1.Field1 = OvrRate.Field1;
```

So far, my code works in showing 1 decimal place, but when it is supposed to be 5.3 it shows 5.0 instead. All of the reviews are stored properly (I think). I have one review of 5.3 which means the average should be 5.3 as well, but like I said above, it is not querying this way.

Any fixes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MS Access does integer arithmetic on integers, so you need to convert the value.  I find the easiest way is to multiply by 1.0:

```
SELECT OvrRate.OvRating, *
FROM tbl1 LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT Field1, ROUND(AVG(Rating*1.0), 1) AS OvRating 
     FROM tbl_Review
     GROUP BY Field1
    )  AS OvrRate 
    ON tbl1.Field1 = OvrRate.Field1;
```

Comment: I tried, and it still isn't coming up with 5.3. Is it possible that it is being caused by the Rating field itself? The rating is a calculated field that multiplies three rating fields, Quality, Price, Customer Service then divides by 3 to solve for the total rating. Those are stored (or at least show up) properly for example as 5.3 for one rating.

Comment: @user3105414 . . . If they are showing up correctly, then your average should work.

Comment: I was looking at how the Rating was stored, and the scale is set to 0. Even if I change it to any number other than 0, save, and exit, the scale always returns to 0 saying that 0 numbers are stored to the right of the decimal place. Could this possibly be the problem? If so, any ideas on how to fix it?

Comment: I got it! I had ([Quality]+[Price]+[Service])/3 as the calculated field for rating, so I multiplied each by 1.0 "(([Quality]*1.0)+([Price]*1.0)+([Service]*1.0))/3" and it fixed it! Basically it changed the field from Decimal to Double.